# Tire sensor dangling from rear of car

Tags: mini-cooper, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

We have a 2014 Mini Cooper Countryman S All4 and I noticed some kind of sensor dangling down near the rear of the car:

- Sensor is blue-circled part
- Something that looks like a "holder clip" is orange-circled

[image: bottom rear of car]

Here's a up-close of both sides of the sensor:
[image: side 1 of sensor]
[image: side 2 of sensor]

I looked up model TSSSG4G5 and it seems to be some kind of [tire/axle sensor](https://fccid.io/OYGTSSSG4G5/User-Manual/User-Manual-1195381). From some translations, I guess it’s the TPMS "reader" that reads the remote sensor that's inside the wheel?

The car was just recently serviced (normal maintenance at a local Mini dealership).

Should I try to clip this sensor back into the apparent "holder clip"? Does it even go there? Or do I call up and/or take it back to the dealership to advise?

Comment: It says "Reifendruck - Kontrolle" which is German for "Tire pressure control"

Comment: @Daniel yup, that's why I think it's a remote sensor reader for the TPMS. I'm just not sure exactly where to snap this thing back in. I'll try snapping it into the "holder clip" later today.

Comment: Can´t imagine it will stay in this clip alone. aren´t there any screw holes?

Comment: @Daniel Hmm good question! It looks like on the right side of the bottom picture there might be screw holes. Here's the same/similar part on [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/bmw-tsssg4g5-2013-mini-cooper-reifendruck-kontrolle-6793122-02-oem-c5/142744489931?hash=item213c3c0fcb:g:xSIAAOSwwWJaw9bM&vxp=mtr). I'll see tonight what I can find out. Thanks!

Comment: You could probably just zip tie it to the bracket if it’s not holding.

Comment: Didn't have a chance to try it out yesterday but I heard back from the Mini technician and they said it does snap in. If that succeeds, I'll answer the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensor indeed does clip into the holder bracket/clips. There are two C-shaped clips and the sensor snaps into them both. It's a fairly snug fit. There are no screws/bolts used to attach it (at least, in this application).

Source: I called the Mini dealership that services the car and they told me that that's where it fits.